# Continually Monitor file creation then set-ACL permissions

Tags: powershell

at the moment I have the following code:

```
$Ac = Get-ACL “C:\test” 
$Ab = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule(“user”,”FullControl”,”Allow”)
$Ac.SetAccessRule($AB)
Set-ACL “C:\test” $Ac
```

This currently gives the user full control to the file. My questions is how can I monitor a specific folder continually and whenever a new file is created, I run the above code on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you're looking for, you can use IO.FileSystemWatcher. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389702/powershell-system-io-filesystemwatcher-on-network-shares-doesnt-work-when-files). If what you're trying to accomplish is just a give a user full control to any files that are put in that directory and this isn't just an exercise to figure out how to monitor a folder, you just have to set up the permissions on the folder to do so. You can get pretty fine grained as far as what you want to do with permissions too.